# How to return awaited value from async function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have following function that promises:

```
function getAdressValidity(inputed_adress){

var isValid = false;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    MapApi.geocodeAddress(inputed_adress, function(err, data) {

        if(err){
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
        resolve(isValid);
    });
  });
}
```

And i consume the promise here:

```
async function isAdressValid(inputed_adress){
var isValid = await getAdressValidity(inputed_adress);
return isValid;
}
```

Then, as soon as my page is loaded i output the result to console:

```
console.log(Order.isAdressValid("1231231232"));
```

Which gives this output:

[image]

If i place console.log like that, it ouputes awaited result:

```
async function isAdressValid(inputed_adress){
var isValid = await getAdressValidity(inputed_adress);
console.log(isValid);
// return isValid;
}
```

Is there a way to wait for the result in other thread, while returning the value in the synchronous matter, like my function is expected to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix async and sync code. Whenever there is something async, you need to wrap it asynchronously:

```
(async function(){

  console.log(await Order.isAdressValid("1231231232"));

})()
```

or the ES6 way:

```
Order.isAdressValid("1231231232").then(console.log);
```

Comment: To explain the ES6 way. Async is actually a promise under the hood, so calling an async function directly in sync code results in a promise being returned.